# Comparing keywords to tweets for gpio activation

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tweepy

I am using a Raspberry Pi and tweepy to control the GPIO pins on the Pi based on tweets. For example, if my tweet says "heating on", a relay gets activated and turns the heating on.

I have managed to read my tweets and print them, but what I can't seem to achieve is comparing key words to tweets to then do something. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def on_status(self, status)
     print (status.text)
     tweet_check = unicode(status.text)
     print tweet_check
     if tweet_check == "heating on":
         print "got it"  # just to confirm capture

def on_error(self, status):
     print status
```

Comment: this is the code i am using   def on_status(self, status):
            print (status.text)
            tweet_check = unicode(status.text)
            print tweet_check
            if tweet_check  == "cat":
                 print "got it"
           return True

Comment: Please add your code in your post, not in a comment. I suggest you have a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: sorry julien lopez

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match keywords in a string:

```
$tweet = 'Please, turn on the heating for me...';
$regex = '/\sheating\s/i';

preg_match($regex, $tweet, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

should print out: `Array([0] => heating)`

So `$matches` array will capture any match.
To see more refer to PHP documentation.

Comment: how would this work with my code, sorry for my ignorance struggling to find my feet here

Comment: It will work just like posting PHP question and then editing it to include Python code. Though, you still able to use regular expressions in Python

Comment: have i posted in the wrong section as i see nothing that suggests i was using php ?? -mister spock

Comment: @markmurfin I retagged your post to Python. You're welcome. You can disregard my comments on PHP, but regular expressions will be your choice for such a task that you described.